# MySQL Error 1064 : Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

thanks, It's work

It was on this 2 line :

```
SET valueName = CONCAT(valueName, ' ,', _valueSplit);
SET valueValue = CONCAT(valueValue,' ,', json(_entryData, _valueSplit));
```

I have declared the variable, but at NULL so CONCAT return NULL and the query go on NULL to

thanks to Devart for helping me

---

### the post :

when I try to use my Stored Procedure I have this error

```
call _extract() Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

but I see nothing in the procedure 
this my procedure, but no instruction NULL on it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _extract()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _entryType VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE _entryData VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE _entryTime BIGINT(20);

    DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE entryCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT entryValue, entryTime FROM TrackingEntry;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

    OPEN entryCursor;
    select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

    mainLoop: LOOP

        FETCH entryCursor INTO _entryData, _entryTime;

        IF no_more_rows THEN
            CLOSE entryCursor;
            LEAVE mainLoop;
        END IF;

        SET _entryType = json(_entryData, "type");
        CALL split_string(json(_entryData, "data"), ",");
        CALL _extractJson(_entryType, _entryData);

    END LOOP mainLoop;
END$$
```

_extractJson procedure :
the next part of the extration of the data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _extractJson(`_entryType` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    DECLARE _valueSplit VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE valueName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE valueValue VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE split_no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE split_num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE splitCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS _value FROM SplitValues;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET split_no_more_rows = TRUE;

    OPEN splitCursor;
    select FOUND_ROWS() into split_num_rows;
    dataLoop: LOOP
        FETCH splitCursor INTO _valueSplit;
        IF split_no_more_rows THEN
            CLOSE splitCursor;
            LEAVE dataLoop;
        END IF;

        SET valueName = CONCAT(valueName, ' ,', _valueSplit);
        SET valueValue = CONCAT(valueValue,' ,', json(_entryData, _valueSplit));

    END LOOP dataLoop;
    SET @query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',_entryType, ' (',valueName,') VALUES (',valueValue,')' );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    --end stuffs here
END$$
```

to explain what i want to do

some Data are stored in trackingEntry, each row contain information about what the user do (in a social game) and where he come from (action, referer, and some other value)

theses data are stored in a Json format like that :
    {
        "type" : "tableName",
        "data" : "row1,row2,row3",
        "row1" : "value",
        "row2" : "value",
        "row3" : "value"
    }

the type of the data (the action (connection, publish on wall)) it's a table's name of one of our dashboard application

The "data" is the list of the available datas

and after we have the Datas

Comment: The problem can be in another procedure or function you call from this procedure. Please provide `json`, `split_string` and `_extractJson` routines, or try to debug them.

Comment: Json and split_str, work perfectfully, I have tested them separatly, I'm going to edit to add _extractJson

Comment: I do not see any errors in your code. Try to comment lines that call additional routenes and run `_extract` again;-)

Comment: when I comment CALL _extractJson(_entryType, _entryData); it's work --" so it's in _extractJson()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be with a prepared INSERT statement, it seems that one of the variables is NULL. Try to comment prepared statements and select @query, you will see the problem -

```
SET @query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',_entryType, ' (',valueName,') VALUES (',valueValue,')' );
SELECT @query;
-- PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
-- EXECUTE stmt;
-- DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: indeed... @query is null... but if "_entryType" or the other is empty, the string must contain, the constant part like 'insert into' right ?

Comment: The @query is NULL because one of `_entryType`, `valueName` or `valueValue` is NULL. From the documentation - CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: [Debugger for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) (try trial version).

Comment: thanks, It's work

It was on this 2 line :

    SET valueName = CONCAT(valueName, ' ,', _valueSplit);
    SET valueValue = CONCAT(valueValue,' ,', json(_entryData, _valueSplit));

I have declared the variable, but at NULL so CONCAT return NULL and the query go on NULL to 

thanks to Devart for helping me

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the select statement, so that the `FOUND_ROWS()` function works.

So change this line

```
DECLARE entryCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT entryValue, entryTime FROM TrackingEntry;
```

like this

```
DECLARE entryCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS entryValue, entryTime FROM TrackingEntry;
```

You can read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).